# class file for org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema not found

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm trying to develop a flink stream job. The job should read from a kafka topic.

I've tried to update the example at https://github.com/dataArtisans/kafka-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dataartisans/ReadFromKafka.java

I want to use Flink 1.4 and Kafka 0.11.

When I try to build the (maven) project I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] /quickstart/src/main/java/org/myorg/quickstart/StreamingJob.java:[20,66] cannot access org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema
  class file for org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema not found
[INFO] 1 error
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project quickstart: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /quickstart/src/main/java/org/myorg/quickstart/StreamingJob.java:[20,66] cannot access org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema
[ERROR] class file for org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema not found
```

Are there any ideas how to resolve this error? So far, I wasn't able to find a solution.

**Files**

StreamingJob.java

```
package org.myorg.quickstart;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer08;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.KeyedDeserializationSchema;

public class StreamingJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // set up the streaming execution environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        // parse user parameters
        ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

        DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer08<String>(parameterTool.getRequired("topic"), (KeyedDeserializationSchema) new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(true), parameterTool.getProperties()));

        // print() will write the contents of the stream to the TaskManager's standard out stream
        // the rebelance call is causing a repartitioning of the data so that all machines
        // see the messages (for example in cases when "num kafka partitions" < "num flink operators"
        messageStream.rebalance().map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;

            @Override
            public String map(String value) throws Exception {
                return "Kafka and Flink says: " + value;
            }
        }).print();

        // execute program
        env.execute("Flink Streaming Java API Skeleton");
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.myorg.quickstart</groupId>
    <artifactId>quickstart</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Flink Quickstart Job</name>
    <url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <flink.version>1.3.0</flink.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.10</scala.binary.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <!-- 

        Execute "mvn clean package -Pbuild-jar"
        to build a jar file out of this project!

        How to use the Flink Quickstart pom:

        a) Adding new dependencies:
            You can add dependencies to the list below.
            Please check if the maven-shade-plugin below is filtering out your dependency
            and remove the exclude from there.

        b) Build a jar for running on the cluster:
            There are two options for creating a jar from this project

            b.1) "mvn clean package" -> this will create a fat jar which contains all
                    dependencies necessary for running the jar created by this pom in a cluster.
                    The "maven-shade-plugin" excludes everything that is provided on a running Flink cluster.

            b.2) "mvn clean package -Pbuild-jar" -> This will also create a fat-jar, but with much
                    nicer dependency exclusion handling. This approach is preferred and leads to
                    much cleaner jar files.
    -->

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Flink dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- explicitly add a standard loggin framework, as Flink does not have
            a hard dependency on one specific framework by default -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Profile for packaging correct JAR files -->
            <id>build-jar</id>

            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.10</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-clients_2.10</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- disable the exclusion rules -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactSet>
                                        <excludes combine.self="override"></excludes>
                                    </artifactSet>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- We use the maven-shade plugin to create a fat jar that contains all dependencies
            except flink and its transitive dependencies. The resulting fat-jar can be executed
            on a cluster. Change the value of Program-Class if your program entry point changes. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <!-- This list contains all dependencies of flink-dist
                                    Everything else will be packaged into the fat-jar
                                    -->
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-annotations</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop2</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-curator-recipes</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-core</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-java</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-runtime_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-optimizer_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-avro_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-examples-batch_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-examples-streaming_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-scala_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-scala-shell_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-python</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-metrics-core</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-metrics-jmx</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-statebackend-rocksdb_2.10</exclude>

                                    <!-- Also exclude very big transitive dependencies of Flink

                                    WARNING: You have to remove these excludes if your code relies on other
                                    versions of these dependencies.

                                    -->

                                    <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-library</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-compiler</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-reflect</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.data-artisans:flakka-actor_*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.data-artisans:flakka-remote_*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.data-artisans:flakka-slf4j_*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>io.netty:netty-all</exclude>
                                    <exclude>io.netty:netty</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.avro:avro</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-collections:commons-collections</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-compress</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.tukaani:xz</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.objenesis:objenesis</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.twitter:chill_*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.twitter:chill-java</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-lang:commons-lang</exclude>
                                    <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-lang3</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-api</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12</exclude>
                                    <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-math</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.commons.json</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-logging:commons-logging</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-codec:commons-codec</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations</exclude>
                                    <exclude>stax:stax-api</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.typesafe:config</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.uncommons.maths:uncommons-maths</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.github.scopt:scopt_*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-io:commons-io</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-cli:commons-cli</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>org.apache.flink:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <!-- exclude shaded google but include shaded curator -->
                                        <exclude>org/apache/flink/shaded/com/**</exclude>
                                        <exclude>web-docs/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                                <filter>
                                    <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                    Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <!-- If you want to use ./bin/flink run <quickstart jar> uncomment the following lines.
                            This will add a Main-Class entry to the manifest file -->
                            <!--
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.myorg.quickstart.StreamingJob</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            -->
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source> <!-- If you want to use Java 8, change this to "1.8" -->
                    <target>1.7</target> <!-- If you want to use Java 8, change this to "1.8" -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <!-- If you want to use Java 8 Lambda Expressions uncomment the following lines -->
        <!--
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tycho-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
                            <version>0.21.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.4,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>single</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        -->
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your flink version says 1.3.0 in your pom.xml.
 Don't you want to use 1.4.1? <flink.version>1.3.0</flink.version>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its because you are trying to use flink 1.3.0 according to your Pom.xml.

```
<flink.version>1.3.0</flink.version>
```

DeserializationSchema is in org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization for 1.3.0. not where its trying to look. Should be able to change the version to 1.4.1 in your pom.xml to

```
<flink.version>1.4.1</flink.version>
```

Comment: Hint: You may need to change the scala version as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```